# MAc application I created works perfectly fine on OSX LIon but crashes with Exception on Snow Leopeard

Tags: objective-c, macos

```
I have created a mac apllication which runs perfectly fine on Lion. But other person has Snow Leopeord and the app fails on launching with below error log

   Process:         MAC_Print_Tool [4889]
Path:            
/Users/a213310/Desktop/MAC_Print_Tool_7.app/Contents/MacOS/MAC_Print_Tool
Identifier:      com.mycompany.MAC-Print-Tool
Version:         1.0 (1)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [140]

Date/Time:       2011-09-16 14:38:29.394 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          1016391 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           24
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  9 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   21
Anonymous UUID:                      083C909E-0F54-4AA7-B973-C0F15E500DFC

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
objc[4889]: garbage collection is ON

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84c900b6 __kill + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84d309f6 abort + 83
2   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00007fff85e4f5d2 __tcf_0 + 0
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff83422b39 _objc_terminate + 100
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00007fff85e4dae1
__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 11
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00007fff85e4db16
__cxxabiv1::__unexpected(void (*)()) + 0
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00007fff85e4dbfc
__gxx_exception_cleanup(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8341efa2 object_getIvar + 0
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff860e45d7 +[NSException
raise:format:arguments:] + 103
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff860e4564 +[NSException
raise:format:] + 148
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86acedfa _decodeObjectBinary
+ 2427
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86ace2ed _decodeObject + 208
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff887311e4 -[NSNibConnector
initWithCoder:] + 406
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88731036
-[NSNibOutletConnector initWithCoder:] + 343
14  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86acee73 _decodeObjectBinary
+ 2548
15  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86acfb79 -[NSKeyedUnarchiver
_decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1229
16  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86ad00b9 -[NSArray(NSArray)
initWithCoder:] + 462
17  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86acee73 _decodeObjectBinary
+ 2548
18  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86ace2ed _decodeObject + 208
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88730351 -[NSIBObjectData
initWithCoder:] + 2046
20  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86acee73 _decodeObjectBinary
+ 2548
21  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86ace2ed _decodeObject + 208
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8872fa41 loadNib + 146
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8872efa1
+[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] +
248
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8872edd9
+[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 326
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8872c35b NSApplicationMain +
279
26  com.mycompany.MAC-Print-Tool    0x0000000100001084 0x100000000 + 4228

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84c5ac0a kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84c5cadd _dispatch_mgr_invoke
+ 154
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84c5c7b4
_dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84c5c2de
_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84c5bc08 _pthread_wqthread +
353
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84c5baa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84c5ba2a __workq_kernreturn +
10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84c5be3c _pthread_wqthread +
917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84c5baa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff708d32f8  rcx:
0x00007fff5fbfe498  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000001319  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp:
0x00007fff5fbfe4b0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfe498
   r8: 0x00007fff708d6a60   r9: 0x0000000000000063  r10:
0x00007fff84c8c0fa  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff86169b09  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14:
0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x00000000000001ef
  rip: 0x00007fff84c900b6  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff709b2fd0

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100001ff7 +com.mycompany.MAC-Print-Tool 1.0
(1) <9B481004-856A-3287-A9EB-6920E0BE9602>
/Users/a213310/Desktop/MAC_Print_Tool_7.app/Contents/MacOS/MAC_Print_Tool
    0x7fff5fc00000 -     0x7fff5fc3bdef  dyld 132.1 (???)
<63B47435-46CF-3D2D-F7F4-7FE77DEEFE06> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff80ec1000 -     0x7fff80efcfff  com.apple.AE 496.5 (496.5)
<208DF391-4DE6-81ED-C697-14A2930D1BC6>
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.
framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff80efd000 -     0x7fff80fbafff  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices
359.2 (359.2) <BBB8888E-18DE-5D09-3C3A-F4C029EC7886>
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSS
ervices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff81005000 -     0x7fff810c6fff  libFontParser.dylib ??? (???)
<A00BB0A7-E46C-1D07-1391-194745566C7E>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
    0x7fff810d9000 -     0x7fff81179fff  com.apple.LaunchServices 362.3
(362.3) <B90B7C31-FEF8-3C26-BFB3-D8A48BD2C0DA>
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Lau
nchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff811ac000 -     0x7fff812e1fff
com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6.7 (1.6.7)
<E5D7DBDB-6DDF-E6F9-C71C-86F4520EE5A3>
/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
    0x7fff812e2000 -     0x7fff81392fff  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.11 (6.5.11)
<085D80F5-C9DC-E252-C21B-03295E660C91>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fff816df000 -     0x7fff81700fff  libresolv.9.dylib 41.0.0
(compatibility 1.0.0) <9F322F47-0584-CB7D-5B73-9EBD670851CD>
/usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff81705000 -     0x7fff81708ff7  libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???)
<E03D7C81-A3DA-D44A-A88A-DDBB98AF910B>
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMC
lient.dylib
    0x7fff81715000 -     0x7fff8175efef  libGLU.dylib ??? (???)
<1C050088-4AB2-2BC2-62E6-C969F925A945>
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dyl
ib
    0x7fff8175f000 -     0x7fff817f9fe7  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS
275.16 (???) <4B70A2FC-1902-5F27-5C3B-5C78C283C6EA>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fff817fa000 -     0x7fff8182bfff  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???)
<7F102A07-E4FB-9F52-B2F6-4E2D2383CA13>
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage
.dylib
    0x7fff819c2000 -     0x7fff81a83fef  com.apple.ColorSync 4.6.6 (4.6.6)
<BB2C5813-C61D-3CBA-A8F7-0E59E46EBEE8>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff81a84000 -     0x7fff81ec7fef  libLAPACK.dylib 219.0.0
(compatibility 1.0.0) <0CC61C98-FF51-67B3-F3D8-C5E430C201A9>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLi
b.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff81ec8000 -     0x7fff81eceff7  com.apple.CommerceCore 1.0 (9.1)
<3691E9BA-BCF4-98C7-EFEC-78DA6825004E>
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Framewor
ks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore
    0x7fff81f05000 -     0x7fff81f05ff7  com.apple.Cocoa 6.6 (???)
<68B0BE46-6E24-C96F-B341-054CF9E8F3B6>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fff82128000 -     0x7fff8213cfff  libGL.dylib ??? (???)
<2ECE3B0F-39E1-3938-BF27-7205C6D0358B>
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dyli
b
    0x7fff8213d000 -     0x7fff82152ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.6
(1.6.6) <1AE1FE8F-2204-4410-C94E-0E93B003BEDA>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fff8218b000 -     0x7fff82198fe7  libCSync.A.dylib 545.0.0
(compatibility 64.0.0) <1C35FA50-9C70-48DC-9E8D-2054F7A266B1>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCSync.A.dylib
    0x7fff821a0000 -     0x7fff822bafef  libGLProgrammability.dylib ???
(???) <8A4B86E3-0FA7-8684-2EF2-C5F8079428DB>
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgr
ammability.dylib
    0x7fff822bb000 -     0x7fff82374fff  libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0
(compatibility 9.0.0) <2C5ED312-E646-9ADE-73A9-6199A2A43150>
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff824e6000 -     0x7fff82535fef  libTIFF.dylib ??? (???)
<1E2593D1-A7F6-84C6-DF8F-0B46AE445926>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
    0x7fff82603000 -     0x7fff827c1ff7  com.apple.ImageIO.framework 3.0.4
(3.0.4) <0A4F51A1-4502-767B-8A4E-F14C6214EF88>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fff827c2000 -     0x7fff827d0ff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???)
<8145A534-95CC-9F3C-B78B-AC9898F38C6F> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff8280e000 -     0x7fff82861ff7  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.3 (???)
<F6E0C7A7-C11D-0096-4DDA-2C77793AA6CD>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff828a8000 -     0x7fff828a8ff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44)
<DC7400FB-851E-7B8A-5BF6-6F50094302FB>
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff828b1000 -     0x7fff828b5ff7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0
(compatibility 1.0.0) <95718673-FEEE-B6ED-B127-BCDBDB60D4E5>
/usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
    0x7fff828eb000 -     0x7fff828f1ff7  IOSurface ??? (???)
<04EDCEDE-E36F-15F8-DC67-E61E149D2C9A>
/System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
    0x7fff82913000 -     0x7fff82925fe7  libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0
(compatibility 3.0.0) <76B83C8D-8EFE-4467-0F75-275648AFED97>
/usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
    0x7fff82926000 -     0x7fff82943ff7  libPng.dylib ??? (???)
<6D8E515B-E0A2-2BA1-9CAC-8CB8A8B35879>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
    0x7fff82a6d000 -     0x7fff82d6bfff  com.apple.HIToolbox 1.6.5 (???)
<AD1C18F6-51CB-7E39-35DD-F16B1EB978A8>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox
.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
    0x7fff82dd8000 -     0x7fff82dffff7  libJPEG.dylib ??? (???)
<46A413EA-4FD1-A050-2EF0-6279F3EAD581>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
    0x7fff82e00000 -     0x7fff83134fef  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore
861.39 (861.39) <1386A24D-DD15-5903-057E-4A224FAF580B>
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Car
bonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff83135000 -     0x7fff831b4fe7  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.2.6
(3.2.6) <79E256EB-43F1-C7AA-6436-124A4FFB02D0>
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
    0x7fff831b5000 -     0x7fff831f6fef  com.apple.QD 3.36 (???)
<5DC41E81-32C9-65B2-5528-B33E934D5BB4>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
    0x7fff831f7000 -     0x7fff832dcfef  com.apple.DesktopServices 1.5.11
(1.5.11) <39FAA3D2-6863-B5AB-AED9-92D878EA2438>
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/
DesktopServicesPriv
    0x7fff83300000 -     0x7fff83348ff7  libvDSP.dylib 268.0.1
(compatibility 1.0.0) <98FC4457-F405-0262-00F7-56119CA107B6>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLi
b.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff83415000 -     0x7fff834cbff7  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0
(compatibility 1.0.0) <03140531-3B2D-1EBA-DA7F-E12CC8F63969>
/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff83517000 -     0x7fff83526fef  com.apple.opengl 1.6.13 (1.6.13)
<516098B3-4517-8A55-64BB-195CDAA5334D>
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff83527000 -     0x7fff83528ff7  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent
1.1 (1) <5952A9FA-BC2B-16EF-91A7-43902A5C07B6>
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A
/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff83529000 -     0x7fff83575fff  libauto.dylib ??? (???)
<F7221B46-DC4F-3153-CE61-7F52C8C293CF> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff83576000 -     0x7fff8357dfff  com.apple.OpenDirectory 10.6
(10.6) <4200CFB0-DBA1-62B8-7C7C-91446D89551F>
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
    0x7fff83581000 -     0x7fff835e1fe7  com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0
(???) <4F071EF0-8260-01E9-C641-830E582FA416>
/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff835e2000 -     0x7fff83660ff7  com.apple.CoreText 151.10 (???)
<54961997-55D8-DC0F-2634-674E452D5A8E>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    0x7fff83661000 -     0x7fff8367afff  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory 10.6
(10.6) <CCF79716-7CC6-2520-C6EB-A4F56AD0A207>
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CF
OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
    0x7fff836e4000 -     0x7fff8370fff7  libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0
(compatibility 3.0.0) <8AB4CA9E-435A-33DA-7041-904BA7FA11D5>
/usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff8376c000 -     0x7fff837d6fe7  libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1
(compatibility 1.0.0) <AF0EA96D-000F-8C12-B952-CB7E00566E08>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLi
b.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff837d7000 -     0x7fff837fcff7  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.2 (45.6)
<E138C8E7-3CB6-55A9-0A2C-B73FE63EA288>
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
    0x7fff83bf5000 -     0x7fff83bf6ff7  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit
1.6.7 (1.6.7) <53299948-2554-0F8F-7501-04B34E49F6CF>
/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
    0x7fff83c35000 -     0x7fff83c46ff7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility
1.0.0) <97019C74-161A-3488-41EC-A6CA8738418C> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff83cc5000 -     0x7fff83de4fe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8
(compatibility 0.9.8) <14115D29-432B-CF02-6B24-A60CC533A09E>
/usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff83e68000 -     0x7fff83e68ff7  com.apple.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6)
<96FB6BAD-5568-C4E0-6FA7-02791A58B584>
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff83e69000 -     0x7fff83f80fef  libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0
(compatibility 10.0.0) <1B27AFDD-DF87-2009-170E-C129E1572E8B>
/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff84750000 -     0x7fff84778fff  com.apple.DictionaryServices
1.1.2 (1.1.2) <E9269069-93FA-2B71-F9BA-FDDD23C4A65E>
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Dic
tionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff84779000 -     0x7fff847c0ff7  com.apple.coreui 2 (114)
<923E33CC-83FC-7D35-5603-FB8F348EE34B>
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
    0x7fff847c1000 -     0x7fff84a4aff7  com.apple.security 6.1.2 (55002)
<4419AFFC-DAE7-873E-6A7D-5C9A5A4497A6>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff84a66000 -     0x7fff84a66ff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices 38
(38) <10A0B9E9-4988-03D4-FC56-DDE231A02C63>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Applica
tionServices
    0x7fff84a67000 -     0x7fff84b3bfe7  com.apple.CFNetwork 454.12.4
(454.12.4) <C83E2BA1-1818-B3E8-5334-860AD21D1C80>
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFN
etwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff84b46000 -     0x7fff84b47fff  liblangid.dylib ??? (???)
<EA4D1607-2BD5-2EE2-2A3B-632EEE5A444D> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x7fff84c41000 -     0x7fff84e02fef  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.11
(compatibility 1.0.0) <9AB4F1D1-89DC-0E8A-DC8E-A4FE4D69DB69>
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff84e05000 -     0x7fff84e8aff7
com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 6.3 (312.7)
<CDFE82DD-D811-A091-179F-6E76069B432D>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff84e8b000 -     0x7fff84eabff7
com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.11)
<AD76C757-6701-BDB5-631E-1CB77D669586>
/System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryS
ervice
    0x7fff84eac000 -     0x7fff84eb2ff7  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3
(2.3) <857F6E43-1EF4-7D53-351B-10DE0A8F992A>
/System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitra
tion
    0x7fff84f72000 -     0x7fff8577cfe7  libBLAS.dylib 219.0.0
(compatibility 1.0.0) <FC941ECB-71D0-FAE3-DCBF-C5A619E594B8>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLi
b.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff857d5000 -     0x7fff857d5ff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.6
(Accelerate 1.6) <15DF8B4A-96B2-CB4E-368D-DEC7DF6B62BB>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff857d6000 -     0x7fff85862fef  SecurityFoundation ??? (???)
<84778E7D-B73C-781A-CD71-7EF5E7EA8EF5>
/System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Security
Foundation
    0x7fff85a56000 -     0x7fff85a5bfff  libGIF.dylib ??? (???)
<201B8077-B5CC-11AA-E1B0-1D057ABE416A>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
    0x7fff85ab0000 -     0x7fff85c6efff  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0
(compatibility 1.0.0) <4274FC73-A257-3A56-4293-5968F3428854>
/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff85c6f000 -     0x7fff85d4cfff  com.apple.vImage 4.1 (4.1)
<C3F44AA9-6F71-0684-2686-D3BBC903F020>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImag
e.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff85d4d000 -     0x7fff85e02fe7  com.apple.ink.framework 1.3.3
(107) <8C36373C-5473-3A6A-4972-BC29D504250F>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.frame
work/Versions/A/Ink
    0x7fff85e03000 -     0x7fff85e80fef  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0
(compatibility 7.0.0) <35ECA411-2C08-FD7D-11B1-1B7A04921A5C>
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff85ecc000 -     0x7fff85f5cfff  com.apple.SearchKit 1.3.0 (1.3.0)
<4175DC31-1506-228A-08FD-C704AC9DF642>
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Sea
rchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff85fec000 -     0x7fff85feefff  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???)
<A9DB4D5D-4072-971B-DEF6-DDE645F415EA>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
    0x7fff86033000 -     0x7fff861aafe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.5
(550.43) <31A1C118-AD96-0A11-8BDF-BD55B9940EDC>
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundati
on
    0x7fff861d0000 -     0x7fff861e4ff7
com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35)
<621B7415-A0B9-07A7-F313-36BEEDD7B132>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff86246000 -     0x7fff86295ff7
com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.1 (6.1)
<01B370FB-D524-F660-3826-E85B7F0D85CD>
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/Passw
ordServer
    0x7fff86296000 -     0x7fff862acfef  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???)
<42D3023A-A1F7-4121-6417-FCC6B51B3E90> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff8637a000 -     0x7fff864b8fff  com.apple.CoreData 102.1 (251)
<9DFE798D-AA52-6A9A-924A-DA73CB94D81A>
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
    0x7fff864e9000 -     0x7fff864f4ff7
com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.11.1 (3.11.1)
<3D65E89B-FFC6-4AAF-D5CC-104F967C8131>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRec
ognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
    0x7fff86939000 -     0x7fff8694ffe7
com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework 207.11 (207.11)
<8233CE71-6F8D-8B3C-A0E1-E123F6406163>
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/Mu
ltitouchSupport
    0x7fff86ac2000 -     0x7fff86d44fe7  com.apple.Foundation 6.6.7
(751.62) <6F2A5BBF-6990-D561-2928-AD61E94036D9>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff86d45000 -     0x7fff87441ff7  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.545.0
(???) <58D597B1-EB3B-710E-0B8C-EC114D54E11B>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fff8748c000 -     0x7fff874affff  com.apple.opencl 12.3.6 (12.3.6)
<42FA5783-EB80-1168-4015-B8C68F55842F>
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
    0x7fff87888000 -     0x7fff878d2ff7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3
(507.15) <2EF19055-D7AE-4D77-E589-7B71B0BC1E59>
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Met
adata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff87e3a000 -     0x7fff881d7fe7  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.6.3
(227.37) <16DFF6CD-EA58-CE62-A1D7-5F6CE3D066DD>
/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
    0x7fff881d8000 -     0x7fff881d8ff7  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib 3.6
(vecLib 3.6) <4CCE5D69-F1B3-8FD3-1483-E0271DB2CCF3>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLi
b.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff88203000 -     0x7fff88208fff  libGFXShared.dylib ??? (???)
<1D0D3531-9561-632C-D620-1A8652BEF5BC>
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShar
ed.dylib
    0x7fff88210000 -     0x7fff88251fff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration
1.10.8 (1.10.2) <78D48D27-A9C4-62CA-2803-D0BBED82855A>
/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemC
onfiguration
    0x7fff882ad000 -     0x7fff88302ff7
com.apple.framework.familycontrols 2.0.2 (2020)
<F09541B6-5E28-1C01-C1AE-F6A2508670C7>
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/Famil
yControls
    0x7fff88685000 -     0x7fff886c2ff7  libFontRegistry.dylib ??? (???)
<4C3293E2-851B-55CE-3BE3-29C425DD5DFF>
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo
rks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
    0x7fff886c3000 -     0x7fff886fdfff  libcups.2.dylib 2.8.0
(compatibility 2.0.0) <7982734A-B66B-44AA-DEEC-364D2C10009B>
/usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
    0x7fff886fe000 -     0x7fff8870dfff  com.apple.NetFS 3.2.2 (3.2.2)
<7CCBD70E-BF31-A7A7-DB98-230687773145>
/System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff8872a000 -     0x7fff89124ff7  com.apple.AppKit 6.6.8 (1038.36)
<4CFBE04C-8FB3-B0EA-8DDB-7E7D10E9D251>
/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fffffe00000 -     0x7fffffe01fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???)
<9AB4F1D1-89DC-0E8A-DC8E-A4FE4D69DB69> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Comment: So what should I do for that? How to make the app running on 10.6? Also I dont see aywhere in my code I am exlicity uising NSTableView cell?

Comment: Since the exception is related to unarchiving - I would have a look for `NSTableViewCell`s in your xib files.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the response guys. I got rid of the NSInvalid... exception, but I still get the exception which is similar to before excpet the NSInvalid... part is gone. I will edit the log file in my question.please have a look

Comment: I have updated the exception I get now. Please let me know what else could be wrong. And it works perfectly fine on any Lion OS I tested

Comment: -1 there is such a thing as too much detail

Answer (score 2):

The `NSTableCellView` class is Mac OS X 10.7 only. It is not supported on 10.6

Comment: It looks like there may be one in your nib file.